# Regex Version of Strip(): Using Function Parameter Directly in Regex Compile

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am working on the 'Regex Version of Strip()' practice problem from Automate the Boring Stuff, Chapter 7. I have seen the use of `'+char+'` to pull a function parameter directly into the regex compile, but I do not understand how this formatting works.

```
def pseudoStrip(inputString, char='\s'):
    stripRegex = re.compile(r'^'+char+'|'+char+'+$')
    print(stripRegex.sub('', inputString))
```

Is `'+char+'` the same as `['+char+']`?

Is there a more readable or Pythonic way of performing this task?

Comment: That's simply string concatenation; for example if `char` is X, the result is `'^X|X+$'`.  Note that the `r` raw prefix is completely useless here, as it applies only to the first character.  It would perhaps be clearer if written with some spaces: `'^' + char + '|' + char + '+$'`

Comment: off topic: usage of raw prefix could take effect here if you use it with f-string: `rf'^{char}|{char}$'` (though it still mean nothing in this specific example)

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Throw your regex here and it will tell you what the expression does: https://regex101.com/#python

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please do not add comments as an answer. This will not help SO. Once you have enough reputation, you can add comments to OP.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the least Pythonic way of doing this problem, but it only uses stuff that's been taught in the book up to this point. It works with all characters except \ (backslash).

```
import re

def regexStrip(string,characters):
    mo = spaceStripRegex.search(string) # Calls upon the global regex for separating left and right white space from content
    string = mo.group(2)    # Isolates the string content from bounding white space and re-assigns it to a variable
    
    characters = '[' + characters + ']' # Stores other characters to be stripped in format compatible with character class
    
    # Regex for stripping other characters contains argument built via string concatenation as opposed to single raw string
    characterStripRegex = re.compile(
        '^' + characters + '*' +    # Zero or more of the characters to be stripped on left side of content
        r'(.*?)' +  # Defines unstripped content as the only group. Nongreedy so as not to include characters to be stripped on right side 
        characters + '*$')  # Zero or more of the characters to be stripped on the right side of the content
    mo = characterStripRegex.search(string)
    string = mo.group(1)
    print(string)
    
# Global regex that groups initial string into left white space, content, and right white space
spaceStripRegex = re.compile(r'''
    ^(\s)*  # Left white space if any
    (.*?)   # String content
    (\s)*$  # Right white space if any
    ''', re.VERBOSE)

string = '  **SpamSpamBaconSpamEggsSpamSpam   '
characters = 'ampS*'

regexStrip(string,characters)
```